# How to use innerHTML to display text

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

for example if i want to display text from javascript side by side like this

text1 text2 text3

so I typed this code

```
<p id=displayText> <p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doSomeThing()
{
  //do something
  document.getElementById("displayText").innerHTML=text1;
  //do something
  document.getElementById("displayText").innerHTML=text2;
  //do something
  document.getElementById("displayText").innerHTML=text3;
}
</script>
```

I got only

text3

how can I do it.

Comment: You have to append the data with the existing one.

Answer (score 3):

`+=` can be problematic when used with the non-standard property `innerHTML`.

You can avoid using `+=` on `innerHTML` by using an extra variable:

```
function doSomeThing()
{
    var progress = "";
    //do something
    progress += text1;
    document.getElementById("displayText").innerHTML = progress;
    //do something
    progress += text2;
    document.getElementById("displayText").innerHTML = progress;
    //do something
    progress += text3;
    document.getElementById("displayText").innerHTML = progress;
}
```

`+=` is problematic if you do:

```
e.innerHTML += '<a href="#">foo';
e.innerHTML += 'bar';
e.innerHTML += '</a>';
```

The actual output HTML will be `<a href="#">foo</a>bar`. How did that happen? Well, when you set the innerHTML to `<a href="#">foo` the browser will try to 'fix' it for you so it adds the `</a>` to make it valid.

---

There are also ways to avoid using `innerHTML` entirely by using the DOM API proper `document.createElement()/createTextNode()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p id=displayText> <p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomeThing()
    {
      var para = document.getElementById('displayText');
      para.innerHTML = para.innerHTML + text1;
      para.innerHTML = para.innerHTML + text2;
      para.innerHTML = para.innerHTML + text3;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you set the texts to the same ID.
Create 3 ids, not only one.

do this or that :

```
function doSomeThing()
{
    //do something
    document.getElementById("displayText").innerHTML = text1;
    //do something
    document.getElementById("displayText").innerHTML += (" "+text2);
    //do something
    document.getElementById("displayText").innerHTML += (" "+text3);
}


function doSomeThing()
{
    //do something
    document.getElementById("displayText1").innerHTML = text1;
    //do something
    document.getElementById("displayText2").innerHTML = text2;
    //do something
    document.getElementById("displayText3").innerHTML = text3;
}

//HTML ?
<span id="displayText1"></span>
<span id="displayText2"></span>
<span id="displayText3"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Merely seach for the element once and also pass the values as array (more dynamic and less limited).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function doSomeThing(v){
                var tE = document.getElementById('displayText');
                if (tE) tE.innerHTML = (v || []).join(' ');
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload = "doSomeThing(['text1', 'text2', 'text3'])">
        <span id = 'displayText'></span>
    </body>
</html>
```